# Finding second last digit of term in recursive series

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

A sequence of numbers $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3},...$ is generated by the formula $a_{1}=3, a_{n+1}=a_{n} + a_{n}^{2}$ for integers $n \geqslant 1$. What is the second last digit of the number $a_{1993}$?

I am not able to recognise a pattern in the last two digits when trying out the recursive formula for the first five iterations. How should this question be approached?

Comment: source of this problem?

Comment: just a question given in school

Comment: The second last digit is either $5$ or $9$.

Comment: But I think it's $9$

Comment: How did you arrive at that?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: where is your answer?

Comment: Does second to last mean second to the left or right.  If $a_{1993} = 1234567890$ do you mean the $2$ or the $9$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we have to find the second last digit of $a_{1993}$ , it is enough to calculate the remainder $a_{1993}$ leaves upon division by $100$.
Note that $a_{n+1}\equiv a_n +a_{n}^2\pmod {100}$

Note that , $a_1=3$ and $a_{1}^2=9$ and $a_2=2$. Using this we can write $$a_2\equiv12\pmod{100}$$ 
$$a_{2}^2\equiv 144\equiv 44\pmod{100}$$ 
$$a_3\equiv a_2+a_{2}^2\equiv 56\pmod{100}$$
$$a_{3}\equiv 56\pmod{100}\implies a_{3}^2\equiv 3136\equiv36\pmod{100}$$
$$a_4\equiv a_3+a_{3}^2\equiv 92\pmod{100}$$
$$a_4\equiv 92\pmod{100}\implies a_{4}^2\equiv 8464\equiv 64\pmod{100}$$
$$a_5\equiv a_4+a_{4}^2\equiv 92+64\equiv 56\pmod{100}$$
Similarly, $a_6\equiv 92\pmod{100}$ ,$a_7\equiv 56\pmod{100}$ and so on.......

This pattern of $56$ and $92$ repeats indefinitely . So , $a_{1993}\equiv 56$ or $92\pmod {100}$. I leave it upto you to find out whether the second last digit is $5$ or $9$.